# Find interests of a user and let it appear only once in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables in my database

A table with users:

```
---------------------
| userId | username |
---------------------
| 1      | john doe |
| 2      | jane doe |
---------------------
```

A list of "interests"

```
---------------------
| intId | interest  |
---------------------
| 1      | books    |
| 2      | cars     |
---------------------
```

And a table in which I save what interests a user has

```
--------------------
| userId | intId   |
--------------------
| 1      | 1       |
| 1      | 2       |
| 2      | 1       |
--------------------
```

Now I also have a web page where I can select one or more interests. Based on that I want
to retrieve the users that have those interests.

So suppose I select "books" and "cars". Then I should get two records back, "jonh doe" and "jane doe".

But the thing is that I'm not really sure how to create a query for this. I could do a simple `LEFT JOIN`. But then
I would get 3 records back. Since "john doe" is interested in "books" AND "cars". But I want each user to appear only
once in the result.

So how should I create this query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT. Possibly you don't want to use LEFT JOIN as you appear to want to return results that match exclusively whereas LEFT JOIN would return null results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it with a `DISTINCT` if you're working with interest names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserName 
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserInterests ui ON ui.userId = u.userId
INNER JOIN Interest i on i.intId = ui.intId
WHERE i.Interest in ('books', 'cars')
```

If you want to do it based on interest IDs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserName
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserInterests ui ON ui.userId = u.userId
WHERE ui.intId in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select username 
from   users u
join
(
Select distinct userid 
from table 
where intid in (1,2)
)t 
on t.userid = u.serid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+u.username
    FROM dbo.UserInterests ui
    INNER JOIN dbo.[user] u ON u.userid = ui.UserId
    WHERE ui.IntId=i.intId
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.Interests i
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would be my preferred method, it should run a little faster than using SELECT DISTINCT in the query.

```
SELECT U.UserName 
FROM Users AS U
WHERE 
EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM UserInterests AS UI 
    INNER JOIN Interest I on I.intId = UI.intId
    WHERE UI.userId = U.userId
        AND I.Interest in ('books', 'cars')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT U.UserName
FROM    Users AS U INNER JOIN
        UserInterest AS UI ON U.userId = UI.userId INNER JOIN
        Interests AS I ON UI.intId = I.intId
```